# FaultDescription:java.lang.ClassCastException - Error while casting HttpTemplate to CommonsHttpClient4XTemplate

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

Problem statement- Getting class castException while casting cbi.receptor.http.HttpTemplate template object to cbi.receptor.http.CommonsHttpClient4XTemplate

Overview- I am trying to type cast template object coming from *cbi.receptor.http.HttpTemplate* to *cbi.receptor.http.CommonsHttpClient4XTemplate* .Below is the piece of code from same.

```
ManageProxy.setProxy((CommonsHttpClient4XTemplate)template, dLogger, proxyFlag, proxyHost, proxyPort);
```

while casting it is throwing error i.e.

```
FaultDescription:java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21 cannot be cast to cbi.receptor.http.CommonsHttpClient4XTemplate
```

Debugging steps- When I am printing class classloader for template object I can see it is coming from default class loader **sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@52cc8049** instead of **cbi.receptor.http.HttpTemplate** and that's why it is not getting casted as desired.

I have checked the required class files are present in my classpath .

Can anyone help me here to debug this issue as I am stuck from last two days only for this issue.Thanks in Advance.

Anshu

Comment: can you make a [minimal reproducibible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your dependency, it will be very helpful

Comment: RE: *When I am printing class classloader for template*... If you want to know or check the actual class then use `template..getClass().getName()`

Comment: @Anshu, how you are printing classloader? moreover , based on error your template reference has a type of ` com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21 `  instead of your desired type `cbi.receptor.http.HttpTemplate`. This means,  when you are calling `ManageProxy.setProxy` method , you are not passing `template ` reference with correct type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to type cast from one class to another, which may not be related and may not be possible. Type casting is intended to either broaden or narrow the scope of an object for a specific purpose. For example, I use type casting to save my class instances in objects to be saved to file. Then I re-cast them to the original scope for use after reading from file.

Perhaps you could create a child class that can extend both classes. This should give you the flexibility to move data between the two or use the data from both. You just need to ensure you properly format the data to be transferred correctly. Does this help at all?